# How to add numbers together from a string with words?

Tags: python, string, try-catch, addition

I'm new to Python and I'm sure that there's a method to do this that I don't know about.  I checked around for my question, and there are many similar ones but I didn't find exactly mine.

The string I have is:

```
"Arkansas 40\n Washington 83\n North Dakota 49\n New Jersey 24"
```

What I want to do is add just the numbers in the string together.

I've written a function that does this using the "try" statement, but "try" requires something to be written to the "except" portion of the indent, and I would just like it to simply discard any exceptions silently.

The output I'm looking for is:

```
196
```

(EDIT)  Wow - there are a LOT of ways to do this, clearly.  I picked the best answer for the very simple task I was trying to accomplish.

Mainly, what I needed to know about was "isdigit()", and when using try statements, the "pass" keyword for exception.

Comment: `except Exception: pass`

Comment: Do you mean the function I wrote?  It just takes a string, uses .split() on it and then for loops through each of the words "try"ing to add the word to X.

Comment: Replace every occurance of `\n` by `,`. Delete everything, that is not a comma or a number. Split by `,`. parse the resulting strings and sum them up. done.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: good way to mask any bugs though. OP, **why** would you want to mask all exceptions? What are you trying to do, catch only *specific* exceptions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works:

```
s = "Arkansas 40\n Washington 83\n North Dakota 49\n New Jersey 24"

sum(int(n) for n in s.split() if n.isdigit())

196
```

Basically the [.isdigit()](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm) method does the trick here. No need for a `try/except` as if there are no numbers in the string, no `n` will meet the `isdigit()` condition, and `sum` will return 0.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> s = "Arkansas 40\n Washington 83\n North Dakota 49\n New Jersey 24"
>>> sum([int(x.split()[-1]) for x in s.split('\n')])
196
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
import re
tot = 0
s = "Arkansas 40\n Washington 83\n North Dakota 49\n New Jersey 24"
for line in s.split('\n'):
    ma = re.search('(\d+)', line)
    if ma:
        tot += ma.group(1)
print tot
```

Answer (score 1):

So what you need to do first is extract the numbers from the string. You can split the string out into chunks using String.split(), and then just test if each is a number by iterating through them, returning only the ones that are integers.
For example, if you have the string s:

```
[int(i) for i in s.split('\n') if i.isdigit()]
```

will create an array of integers. Then all you have to do is sum them up, and there's your answer.

Answer (score 0):

wonderful opportunity to abuse `map`,`filter` &  `reduce`

```
print reduce(lambda x,y: x+y, 
             map(lambda x: int(x), 
                 filter(lambda x: x.isdigit(), 
                        re.split(' |\n',s))))
```